# Understanding PHP type coercion

Tags: php, type-conversion, dynamic-typing

I saw this small piece of code that is evading my understanding:

```
<?php

$a = '0e462097431906509019562988736854';
$b = '0e830400451993494058024219903391';

var_dump($a == $b);
```

Which will output:

```
bool(true)
```

I understand that when using `==`, PHP will attempt fuzzy comparison, silently converting between types in order to perform the comparison. What I'm *not* understanding is why PHP seems to think these two strings are the same. I would have thought since `$a` and `$b` are strings, that no type conversion would need to take place.

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this article explains it pretty well:

*[Type-coercing comparison operators will convert numeric strings to numbers](http://phpsadness.com/sad/47)*

Just to quote the main issue here:

> According to [php language.operators.comparison](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison), the type-coercing comparison operators will coerce both operands to floats if they both look like numbers, even if they are both already strings:

where both *strings* are using exponential notation, hence are treated as numeric strings, making loose comparison (`==`), coerce these *strings* to *floats* before actually "loosely" comparing them.

As a best practice and to prevent unexpected behaviour, always try to use [identity equality](http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (`===`), **especially** when dealing with *strings*.

Answer (score 1):

PHP attempts to convert to type float because the string begins with a 0.  It stops after 0 because the next character is not a number.  The same thing happens when you use type coercion to convert scientific notation to integer:

```
$x = (float)"12E-1x";  // $x == 1.2
$x = (int)"12E-1x";  // $x == 12 (stops at E because it's not an integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really an answer, but if you try

```
$a = '0e4620974319065090195629887368549';
$b = '0e8304004519934940580242199033918';
echo floatval($a) . '<br>' . floatval($b);var_dump($a == $b);
```

you get:

```
0

0

bool(true)
```

Now, if you try:

```
$a = '0e4620974319065090195629887368549';
$b = '1e8304004519934940580242199033918';
echo floatval($a) . '<br>' . floatval($b);var_dump($a == $b);
```

you get:

```
0

INF

bool(false)
```

My guess is that PHP converts the strings to floats and gives comparison result using the floats obtained, which are not correct anyway, but that is another story.

Comment: But why, when both are strings?

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation, the test of equality between two variable is made as follows:

```
$a == $b # Equal TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
```

#### Example

```
$a = 13;   # Integer type
$b = "13"; # String type
var_dump($a == $b); # Will say TRUE, because juggling was made
var_dump($a === $b); # Will say FALSE, because PHP will also evaluate the type of variables :)
```